# Missing "Artifacts" from uber jar using IntelliJ / Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, artifact

I am developing a Flink application, and I'm very new to building Java applications.

I am using IntelliJ 2022.2.3 Community Edition, and Maven for dependency management.

I have the following dependencies in my POM file:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I build the artifact and view its contents, I notice that some of the dependancies are included, and others are missing. I expect to see the postgressql drivers at org/postgressql/... but that folder does not exist.

I have a copy of the project where the artifacts folder does contain the expected folders and when I look at the project settings/artifacts/output layout view, the postgres jars are in the list, but not in my problem project?

I read [How can I create an executable/runnable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-runnable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) and i don't have that section in the POM, but in my case as I mentioned the 2 projects I have seem to have different artifacts missing from the jar?

Sorry for my lack of correct terminology.

UPDATE:
I should add this section is in my POM

```
<!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>vendor.flink.StreamProcessingNoJoin</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide this answer for anybody like myself - a beginner with the Java build ecosystem, and maybe IntelliJ.

I was not aware that the "default" IntelliJ build / build artifacts was using the IntelliJ build system and not the configured package manager. In my case, I was following IntelliJ instructions on building an artifact, but using Maven.

The simple answer in my case to correctly generate shaded jars was just to Maven to package the jar. View > Tool Windows > Maven, right click on the package node under Lifecycle and click `run maven build`